# html font/text color does not change on print page preview and when printed out

Tags: html, css

So, I have a report html file that i'm generating and there are black boxes which require white texts/fonts in it. Everything is fine in a generic html display but when i try to print the page, ctrl + p or a custom print function, the text/fonts remain as their standard color, and not white.

Here are the codes I have;

**CSS**

```
@media print {
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-size: 6px;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .fprint{
        background-color:black !important;
        color:white !important;
        font-size:8px;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; 
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 fprint" style="background-color:black; color:white">
  <p class="margB0 lang" tkey="name" style="padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px; padding-left:1px">PART 1 CFS CUSTOMER ACCEPTANCE CHECK</p>
</div>
```

Note that the background color changes just fine. But font color does not. What am I doing wrong here or what can be done to ensure that the font color is white on print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly add the following CSS line:

```
.fprint p{
    color:white !important;
}
```